# Converting string to static constant

Tags: objective-c

I have in my objective-c application a number of constants that I need to have inputted from an external source using strings. The reason of course, is that constants are better to work with, but can't be passed external.

I have made this objective-c code to convert, and it works 100%, but a) it is ugly, and b) quite obscure. I suppose I could have converted to NSNumber and made an array, but that seems like a lot of code/processing (though maybe the right solution)

Can anyone provide a better solution?

```
NSArray *types = @[@"text_input",@"textbox",@"select",@"yesno",@"date",@"signature",@"label",@"SectionHeading"];
    int indexes[10];
    indexes[0] = FieldTypeTextInput;
    indexes[1] = FieldTypeTextBox;
    indexes[2] = FieldTypeSelect;
    indexes[3] = FieldTypeYesNo;
    indexes[4] = FieldTypeDate;
    indexes[5] = FieldTypeSignature;
    indexes[6] = FieldTypeLabel;
    indexes[7] = FieldTypeSectionHeading;
    for (int i=0;i<[types count];i++)
    {
        NSString *string_i = [types objectAtIndex:i];
        if ([type_string isEqualToString:string_i])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use an `NSDictionary`.

```
enum YourNiceTypes : NSInteger {FieldNotFound, FieldTypeTextInput, FieldTypeTextBox, ...};

NSDictionary *types = @{"text_input" : @(FieldTypeTextInput), ... };

enum YourNiceType type = [types[textInput] integerValue];
```

You used the trick to define wrong input with zero, which will be handled automatically correctly, as calling `integerValue` on a `nil` object will return `0`.

Comment: It looks very good with the @(). Of course objectForKey can also be used instead of FieldNotFound. So far I prefer this, but may change my mind or use both.

Comment: Yes, there are several options for non-existing values. You might just want to check against nil, this also works with types[textInput]. Manual checking is always necessary if 0 is a valid value.